# Manga where a moon girl protects a high school boy?

Tags: story-identification, manga

I think it starts with the boy receiving a gift from his dad, containing a kind of emblem through which you allegedly can channel a personal protector.

At first he doesn‘t believe but then this moon goddess/girl appears in his living room, channelled by the emblem. She was trapped in there since medieval times which makes her be really confused throughout the day.

Comment: I'm at a loss why this is got a downvote. It seems very straightforward and (aside from a couple of typos) reasonably well written

Answer (score 4):

Could this be *[Mamotte Shugogetten!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mamotte_Shugogetten) (AKA まもって守護月天!)*?

> The story involves Tasuke Shichiri, a 14-year-old boy that receives a
> gift from his father, Tarousuke, who is traveling in China. The gift
> is a ring, the shitenrin, and those pure of heart may gaze into it and
> receive a moon goddess named Shaorin... A moon spirit who wears traditional styled costumes, she has little understanding of the human world after spending a few thousand years in the confines of the shitenrin
>
> [image]